# Real Time data in Django

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket, channel

I want to observe data changes in real time in python to create a program that show list of online friends (i.e. every time a friend become online or offline I want update a list). I have a function that make an infinite loop to receive the presence a from am XMPP server. I can't seem to figure out how I could receive data in real-time and update. I use Django for backend and i want ti serve this data to a web page to show online Friends. I tried with Channels, but it’s unuseful for this case.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl. ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
sock.connect((hostname, port))

sock.sendall(“<presence/>”.encode())

while True:
  response = sock.recv(1024)
```

How can i pass this results to my page view every time i get new update insidie loop?

Answer (score 0):

How are Channels 'not useful'? From where I stand it's the best approach you could utilize. Sockets are too low level to use in this case, I mean how will you utilize them in your browser. Django doesn't support keep alive connections; that leaves channels (websockets) which are supported out-of-the-box by JS and can actually persist entire time a user in online. You can implement a looping event in JS (user's end) which sends messages to your server via the websocket to show the user is still online, the user's friends will all share/subscribe to his/her channel and can all be notified of her online status. Just my thoughts yo
Could be something like this:

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

from Accounts.models import Profile 

class OnlineStateConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    #Might consider using `database_sync_to_async` to reduce additional IO overhead
    def connect(self):
        #Subscribe to all friends online-notification-channel
        #How you implement friendship for each user and store it is upto you
        #Most probably a many-to-many relationship
        friends = Profiles.objects.filter(friend=self.scope['user'])
        for friend in friends:
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(friend.user.username, self.channel_name)

        self.update_status(True)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        #Tell folks a user is no longer online
        self.update_status(False)

        #Unsubscribe to all friends online-notification-channel
        friends = Profiles.objects.filter(friend=self.scope['user'])
        for friend in friends:
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(friend.user.username, self.channel_name)
    def receive(self, text_data):
        #This is the method called each time a user sends data to the websocket
        #Update online status of user to friends
        #This is triggered for all connections that are subscribed to this user online-state-channel
        
        #self.update_status(True)

    def online_status(self, event):
        #This is handler function that sends data down each websocket
        data = json.dumps({"online":event["text"]})
        self.send(text_data=data)

    def update_status(state=True):
        #Update online status of user to friends
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.scope['user'].username,
            {
                "type": "online.status",
                "text": state,
            },
        )
```

Also you'll have to configure the channel_layer backend in settings.py as well as routes etc. For more info check [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) link.

Comment: The problem is that i use an infinite loop to receive information about presences. So i have lot of problema to trigger events in channels. How should I implement consumer? And how could I pass this data to consumer?

Comment: I'm guessing the infinite loop is implemented in user's end (JS). In your backend you'll have to implement a consumer; inherit from `WebsocketConsumer`. Could be something like this: --I'll post another answer with the code

Comment: No, the infinite loop is implemented in backend django, out of a consumer, to connect to an XMPP server and receive info.

Comment: You can change the code to fit your need. Implementing a loop in the backend will force you to find a way of checking if a user is still online, how you'll do that I don't know maybe you could share your trick. you can go ahead and call `update_state()` passing a bool to show the user online state.